# How do FLIR cameras work with multiple spectral image acquisition?

Tags: infrared, thermal, camera, image-sensor

I am looking to buy a FLIR camera, but it is hard to get in contact with the company. I wonder if somebody already used, or has knowledge about my question, which FLIR cameras can capture images in infrared, thermal and visible spectra (RGB)?

And, how does that acquisition work? I've noticed that for many cases the datasheet, manuals and Youtube, come short on this information. Is there a GUI to choose, do I need a software specifically, or are they fused altogether? Also, on the same note, I would like to know the same things for the LEPTON 3.0 - 3.5 module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an FLIR E series camera, they work with two cameras (infrared and visible) and overlay the images on one another. Sometimes not very well.

The L[epton only works with infrared (not visible) and has two outputs][1]

> Spectral range - Longwave infrared, 8 μm to 14 μm

The spectral range is the wavelength which is 8 to 14um

> Output format - User-selectable 14-bit, 8-bit (AGC applied), or 24-bit
> RGB (AGC and colorization applied)

The output format can be different *bit formats* meaning you can get a grayscale, or you can get an output that is mapped to RGB, but the datasource is the same infrared sensor.

If you want to use the Lepton, then you could use an arudino or other microprocessor to read the SPI output of the sensor
[1]: https://groupgets.com/manufacturers/flir/products/lepton-3-0

Comment: Interesting and can you tell me if i am able to set it as controller/transmitter via USB? what are the infrared image sizes generated?

Comment: I would suggest you read the product page, because it has many answers. The image size is 160 x 120. I depends on what you connect to the module, but the Lepton module by itself does not have a usb output, only a spi output.

Comment: I meant the image size in kB/Mb, i am considering doing a serial interface with more than 1 microcontrollers

Comment: Take the # of bits (160x120=19200) and multiply it by the size (14bits) and there you go, if your using an RGB then it would be 24bits (3x8bits). The frame rate is 8.7Hz.